# Why does Visual Studio accept PriorityQueue?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, f#

I'm writing a program that needs a priority queue, and it would be nice if I could use the one that comes with .Net 6: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.priorityqueue-2?view=net-6.0

So I've tried writing some sample code (in F#, but this particular code fragment could be written just the same in C# and I would expect the results to be the same):

```
open System.Collections.Generic

...

let pq = PriorityQueue()
pq.Enqueue("apple", 5)
pq.Enqueue("banana", 6)
checkEq (pq.Dequeue()) "apple"
checkEq (pq.Dequeue()) "banana"
```

Visual Studio is perfectly happy with that, autocomplete worked and everything.

I try to compile it, and fsc is not at all happy:

> C:\olivine\src\test.fs(1345,14): error FS0039: The value or constructor 'PriorityQueue' is not defined.

Maybe that's because I don't have the right version of .Net installed.

```
reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP" /s
```

Needless to say, there seem to be dozens of versions installed, but the highest version numbers I am seeing, appear to be 4.x, which would explain why fsc is not happy.

But then what's up with Visual Studio? How did it accept and understand the reference to PriorityQueue, despite .Net 6 being apparently not installed on the machine?

Comment: That registry location will only contain versions for 4.x and lower. For .NET core, see HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\dotnet\Setup\InstalledVersions. But better, run dotnet --list-sdks at a terminal prompt to list installed SDKs (or --list-runtimes for runtimes, or --info  for both). If I just create a .Net 6 F# console project in VS 2022 with your code, it works. Where are you seeing the Fsc message? Building from VS actually calls Msbuild, not Fsc directly.

Comment: @JimFoye That clarifies some things, thanks! I'm running fsc directly from the command line. (I subscribe to the Joel Spolsky school of thought that says it's okay to use a whizzy tool to save time, but it's not okay to use it to do magic that you have no idea how to replicate, and would be helpless if it stopped working.) Do you know how Msbuild gets fsc to use the correct .net version? `fsc --help` doesn't list any options that explicitly refer to such.

Comment: Are you familiar with the internals of fsc? Would you not be helpless if it stopped working? It seems like a line is being drawn somewhat arbitrarily here.

Comment: Msbuild has some predefined tasks that it relies on to know how to call fsc. Go to Options and turn on the Msbuild output to maximum verbosity (there are several settings, actually, I think "Diagnostics" is the one you want). Then rebuild from Visual Studio. Now instead of the usual minimal output you'll get a ton of messages. You'll see Msbuild is finding a task (I think the name of the task is actually "fsc"), it tells you where it is locating fsc.exe, etc. ,etc. That should be helpful. Needless to say, most of us just let msbuild do hard work here.

Comment: @JimFoye That helps, thanks! For future reference, the command line switch to get MSbuild to explain what it's doing is `-verbosity`.